# Эмуляция нажатия ctrl + v

Tags: c#, winforms

Необходимо эмулировать нажатие данных клавиш вне формы.

```
SendKeys.Send("^{v}");
```

нажимает просто v

```
SendKeys.Send("^v");
SendKeys.Send("^(v)");
```

Соответственно, тоже.
Winforms net framework 4.5. Тестировал на windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так ли обязательно именно CTRL+V? Может быть стоит взять текст из буфера обмена: [Clipboard.GetText()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard.gettext?view=netframework-4.8). А затем напечатать его. Такой подход даст вам контроль над печать. Можете симулировать пользовательский ввод, добавляя случайную задержку между клавиш.

Comment: Спасибо. Такой вариант подойдёт, но всё же интересно, почему предложенный мной вариант с SendKeys.Send("^v"); не работает, ведь в msdn он указан.

Comment: Как подсказывает гугл, v необходимо обрамлять в фигурные скобки: ^{v}